# Why does an HTTP header sent to my Smart Home webhook indicate API version v1, when I am using v2?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

Our project was created after May 2017, therefore we believe it is using the v2 Google Assistant API, in accordance with what the documentation says [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/v1/migration).

However, the 'Google-Assistant-API-Version' header in HTTP requests sent to our webhook contains the value 'v1'.

```
Google-Assistant-API-Version: v1
```

All the content is using camelCase, rather than snake_case, however, so it does appear to be using v2. As far as we can tell, we are also responding using the v2 format, and this works fine.

We also include the 'Google-Assistant-API-Version' header in our responses with the value 'v2'. For testing purposes we have both removed this header entirely and changed its value to 'v1'. In both cases, the skill continues to function normally.

I have also attempted to change my action package to include the 'fulfillmentApiVersion' field (as described [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/ConversationFulfillment)), but it doesn't appear to have any effect.

```
{
  "actions": [{
      "name": "actions.devices",
      "deviceControl": {},
      "fulfillment": {
        "conversationName": "automation"
      }
    }
  ],
  "conversations": {
    "automation": {
      "name": "automation",
      "url": "https://**************************",
      "fulfillmentApiVersion": 2
    }
  }
}
```

While we are not experiencing any problems at this time, we wonder if this is a sign of some dormant error, and were wondering if anyone could offer some clarification?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Assistant API version may be incorrect, or it may be referring to the API version for Smart Home. The [Smart Home](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/) APIs launched publicly around May and use a different protocol for the data returned from the webhook.

If you are building a Smart Home application, please refer to the documentation above on how to write your webhook responses.